# url and name spaces java convertion

Tags: java, url, namespaces

I need to be able to convert:

```
(url) http://www.joe90.com/showroom
```

to

```
(namespace) com.joe90.showroom
```

I can do this using tokens etc, and a enforced rule set.

However, is there a way (a java package) that will do this for me?
or do i need to write one myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://www.joe90.com/showroom");
String tokens[] = url.getHostname().split(".");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
  if (i > 1) {
    sb.append('.');
  }
  sb.append(tokens[i]);
}
String namespace = sb.toString();
```

Alternatively you can parse the hostname out.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+://)?(.*?)/");
Matcher m = p.matcher(url); // string
if (m.matches()) {
  String tokens[] = m.group(2).split(".");
  // etc
}
```

Of course that regex doesn't match all URLs, for example:

```
http://username@hostname.com/...
```

That's why I suggested using java.net.URL: it does all the URL validation and parsing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to split the string based on the `.` and `/` characters (e.g. using `Sting.split()`, and then concatenate the pieces in reverse order, skipping over any you don't want to include (e.g. `www`)